# Better mysql select Query to filter data (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am having a problem where i want to search data from my mysql database , this is how it goes i have a search field where a user enters location name and then i search for that location in my database and display the username based on searched location but i have some users which have more than one location in the database separated with a "comma" so my select query is not able to find, this is how my database looks

```
 table name :- users 

 username ||  location

 john    ||  KIS,ITS

 alex   || KIS
```

So when someone is searching for KIS it is only showing alex name not john's though he is a part of KIS aswell , i am wondering if there is any better query that can solve my problem

Thanks

Comment: Do you accept that entering *KIS* you get location like *KISK* or *KIST* too? Or location must be entered correctly?

Comment: As a side point I would restructure your data to make queries like this easier (and probably faster). I would have a separate table for "location" and have a new table to link your users to your locations.

Answer (score 1):

Updated query for new question requirements

Works for

> KIS
>
> KIS,(anything) at start
>
> (anything),KIS,(anything) at middle
>
> (anything),KIS at last

Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE location = 'KIS' OR LIKE 'KIS,%' OR LIKE '%,KIS,%' OR LIKE '%,KIS'
```

Comment: sorry that doesn't work for me becuase i need correct location not similar to KIS :-(

Comment: Updated answer for exact match

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find a part of input string you could use

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE location LIKE '%KIS%'
```

If you need to get correct input you can use

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(LOWER('KIS'), LOWER(location)) > 0
```

Comment: @kevin: I see now your comment; well, use my second example and your job should be done :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select username from users where location like '%KIS%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE location RLIKE '(^|[^_alnum])KIS($|[^_alnum])'
```

Or if your data is always separated by one comma, then use this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE location RLIKE '(^|,)KIS($|,)'
```

But know that your database is not in 1st normal form, and storing complex data, and looking it up is going to greatly affect performance. If it's possible use a separate table to store the location for each user.

Comment: Thanks Zsolt that seems to be the real help and yes i will learn follow all the best practices coz i am learning a lot here on stack overflow